# Terraform: How to avoid cycle between `aws_mskconnect_connector` and `aws_iam_role`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

1. `aws_mskconnect_connector` requires `service_execution_role_arn` to be set.
2. To create this role, an `assume_role_policy` must be provided to `aws_iam_role`.
3. And this policy [must refer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-connect-service-execution-role.html) to `aws_mskconnect_connector` from step 1.

**How can the above cycle (1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1) be avoided?** All above steps in snipped TF:

```
# 1.
resource "aws_mskconnect_connector" "this" {
  # ...
  service_execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.this.arn # 1 -> 2
}

# 2.
resource "aws_iam_role" "this" {
  name               = ""
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.this.json  # 2 -> 3
}

# 3.
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "this" {
  statement {
    # ...
    condition {
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      test     = "ArnLike"
      values = [aws_mskconnect_connector.this.arn] # 3 -> 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `condition` test is `ArnLike` - it does not need to be a complete ARN. `ArnLike` allows wildcards. Use something like `arn:aws:kafkaconnect:us-east-1:123456789012:connector/*` to match any connector in your account in the us-east-1 region. Refer to [the docs on Amazon Resource Name (ARN) condition operators](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_ARN) for more details.

Comment: This would work. Though is there a way to have exact `ArnLike` `values`? In this case, to _only_ permit role assumption on this MSK Connector.

Comment: I believe the arm will contain the name, so you could use that, e.g. `arn:aws:kafkaconnect:us-east-1:123456789012:connector/<name>*`. Or sometimes the end of the arn is exactly the resource name, in which case you don’t need the wildcard at all.